# Combining parallel sentences

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns

How best to combine the following two sentences?:

> Trust you enjoyed your drive to the lake to join your family. And trust you enjoyed your time at the lake with your family.

The following isn't quite correct:

> Trust you enjoyed your drive to, and time at, the lake to join your family.

because "time at" requires "with" rather than "to join".

Comment: Why would you exclude the time you spent at the lake from the trip? The trip does include the stay or the visit.

Comment: Reworded by replacing "trip" with "drive." The nature of the enjoyment one has during a drive would be different from that of the one one has at the destination.

Comment: The meaning is unclear.  What does "Trust you enjoyed" mean?  If you're telling someone to trust something, how would that be in the past?

Comment: "Trust you did well in the exam." has an implied "i" and so stands for "I trust you did well in the exam." and is another way of saying "I assume you ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest:

*Trust you enjoyed your drive to the lake to join your family and / as well as the time you spent with them (there).*

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, as with any expression where you use different prepositional phrases before a noun, you have to separate out the parts that are different. In this case, it also helps with parsing if you repeat the *your* in the second part:

> Trust you enjoyed  <sup>your drive to the lake to join</sup> and <sup>your time at the lake with</sup>  your family.

The noun at the end of the first part is suspended until the end of the sentence is reached.

With that basic construction, you can choose to make the second component restrictive or nonrestrictive.

---

If it's restrictive:

> Trust you enjoyed your drive to the lake to join and time at the lake with your family.

---

If it's nonrestrictive (there are multiple ways of punctuating it):

> Trust you enjoyed your drive to the lake to join, and your time at the lake with, your family.
> Trust you enjoyed your drive to the lake to join—and your time at the lake with—your family.
> Trust you enjoyed your drive to the lake to join  (and your time at the lake with) your family.